# branch.io read deep linking not run the listener when new link scanned

Tags: ios, react-native, branch.io

I implement react native app with qr scanner and branch io.
I scan qr code that works with branch io. 
first i run the branch.subscriber to let listen to any new link.
when I scan qr code with the camera in the app, I don't see that the branch.subscriber works or any change in console.log.
in the componentDidMount I run the branch.subscriber but any when i scan any data I see it in onSucess(e) function but the subscriber not run again

do i implement it right??

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

// third party library
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';
import I18n from '../../i18n'
import branch from 'react-native-branch'

// import styles
import { style } from './style';
const { centerText, textBold,  buttonTouchable,  camera, topViewStyleQR, QRcontainer, customMarkerStyle, imageScanStyle,  textScanStyle, sloganScan, viewSlogan, buttonText} = style;

class QrScan extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      barcodeText:''
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error from Branch: " + error)
        return
      }

      console.info("Received link response from Branch")

      console.log("params: " + JSON.stringify(params))
    })
  }


  onSuccess(e) {

    // Linking
    //   .openURL(e.data)
    //   .catch(err => console.error('An error occured', err));
    this.setState({barcodeText:e.data});
    console.log(e);
  }
  _renderMaker(){
    return(
      <View style={customMarkerStyle}>
          <Image 
          style={imageScanStyle}
          source={require('../../assets/images/iconScanP.png')}/>

          <Text style={textScanStyle}>{I18n.t('_scanDrink')}</Text>
          <View style={viewSlogan}>
            <Text style={sloganScan}>SCANDIT</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <QRCodeScanner
        onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)}
        showMarker = {true}
        camType='front' 
        topViewStyle={topViewStyleQR}
        containerStyle={QRcontainer}
        cameraStyle={camera}
        customMarker = {this._renderMaker()}
        bottomContent={(
          <TouchableOpacity style={buttonTouchable}>
            <Text style={buttonText}>{this.state.barcodeText? this.state.barcodeText: ''}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}




export default QrScan;
```

just if i uncomment these lines and go back again to the app I can see the result from branch

```
  // Linking
    //   .openURL(e.data)
    //   .catch(err => console.error('An error occured', err));
```

Comment: I think you need to use this https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking#programmatic-deep-linking